# Box2D distanceJoint not maintaining shape in AndEngine

Tags: android, box2d, andengine

I am using Box2D distanceJoint with AndEngine to maintain a shape. But the shape is not maintained the pieces just fall to the floor. It is supposed to maintain a circular/elliptical shape. Can you let me know what I am doing wrong? Here I am maintaining the distance with the neighbor. Should I maintain the distance with every other member?

```
    for (int i=1; i<nBodies; ++i) {
        FIXTURE_DEF = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(25f, 0.0f, 1f);

        float angle = map(i, 0, nBodies, 0, 2*3.1415f);
        float x = cx + rx * (float)Math.sin(angle);
        float y = cy + ry * (float)Math.cos(angle);
        // Add plate    
        float x1 = (x + 10) * 30;
        float y1 = y * 20;
        centers[i][0] = x1;
        centers[i][1] = y1;

          Vector2 v1 = new Vector2(x1,y1);

          circle = new AnimatedSprite(x1, y1, this.mCircleFaceTextureRegion, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
          circleBody[i] = PhysicsFactory.createCircleBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, circle, BodyType.DynamicBody, FIXTURE_DEF);
          this.mPhysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(circle, circleBody[i], true, true));

          this.mScene.attachChild(circle);

    }

    for(int i= 1;i < nBodies -1; i++)  {

        Vector2 v1 = new Vector2(centers[i][0]/PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO_DEFAULT,centers[i][1]/PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO_DEFAULT);
        Vector2 v2 = new Vector2(centers[i+1][0]/PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO_DEFAULT,centers[i+1][1]/PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO_DEFAULT);
        Log.d("Vals","vals x:" + centers[i][0] + "y:" + centers[i][1] + "x:" +centers[i+1][0] + "y:" + centers[i+1%19][1]);
        int j = i+1;
        Log.d("i","i" + i + "   " + j);
        distanceJoint.initialize(circleBody[i], circleBody[(i+1)], v1, v2);
        distanceJoint.collideConnected = true;
        distanceJoint.dampingRatio = 10.0f;
        distanceJoint.frequencyHz = 1.0f;
        this.mPhysicsWorld.createJoint(distanceJoint);
    }

    Vector2 v1 = new Vector2(centers[1][0]/PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO_DEFAULT,centers[1][1]/PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO_DEFAULT);
    Vector2 v2 = new Vector2(centers[19][0]/PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO_DEFAULT,centers[19][1]/PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO_DEFAULT);
    distanceJoint.initialize(circleBody[1], circleBody[19], v1, v2);
    distanceJoint.collideConnected = true;
    distanceJoint.dampingRatio = 10.0f;
    distanceJoint.frequencyHz = 1.0f;
    this.mPhysicsWorld.createJoint(distanceJoint);
```

Am I missing anything? Do let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have solved it by maintaining a distance joint between every body. I was trying to recreate the Blob demo in http://www.jbox2d.org/. This demo used a ConstantVolumeJoint. I have been able to recreate this with a distance joint between every body as follows

```
    for(int i= 0;i < nBodies-1; i++)  {

       for(int j=i+1; j< nBodies ; j++){
           Vector2 v1 = new Vector2(centers[i][0]/PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO_DEFAULT,centers[i][1]/PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO_DEFAULT);
           Vector2 v2 = new Vector2(centers[j][0]/PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO_DEFAULT,centers[j][1]/PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO_DEFAULT);
           Log.d("Vals","vals x:" + centers[i][0] + "y:" + centers[i][1] + "x:" +centers[j][0] + "y:" + centers[j][1]);

           Log.d("i","i:" + i + " j:" + j);
           distanceJoint.initialize(circleBody[i], circleBody[(j)], v1, v2);

           distanceJoint.collideConnected = true;
           distanceJoint.dampingRatio = 10.0f;
           distanceJoint.frequencyHz = 0.5f;
           this.mPhysicsWorld.createJoint(distanceJoint);
       }
    }
```

I now need to have a connecting line between the bodies. Otherwise the blob does bounce off a body dropping on it.

Please let me know how to draw a connecting line between adjacent bodies that maintain the connection as the whole shape moves?